# Explicit formula for a right splitting once we have a left splitting

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

Assume we have a short exact sequence (of abelian groups or vector-spaces, it doesn't matter)

$$0\rightarrow A\stackrel{\iota}\rightarrow B\stackrel{\pi}\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0.$$

If we have a left splitting $t$, is there a formula for the right splitting $s$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a mapping, $s:C\to B$ would send a $c\in C$ to $$b-\iota t(b)\ \in B$$ for any $b\in\pi^{-1}(c)$. Prove that this is independent of the choice of $b$.